# How to replace the blanks in a column of a dataframe with another value?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that has some blanks (which appear as 'nan'). How do I replace those blanks with the string 'none'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use fillna: `df[col].fillna('none')`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the 'nan' appear as string data type. If they are np.nan, then you can just do df.fillna('none').

If they are strings, then try the following code (don't try to execute it in stack overflow. It won't work here, since this is an HTML interface, but this is python code):

```html
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Col 1'] = ['nan', 'val1', 'val2', 'nan']
df['Col 2'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

#This generates a sample dataset. Now for the column you have 'nan's in:

df['Col 1'] = df['Col 1'].replace('nan', 'none')
df
```

This should give you what you want.